# No funciona el resaltado de sintaxis

Tags: bug, estado-completado, resaltado-de-sintaxis

[La primera pregunta de es.stackoverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/la-creaci%c3%b3n-manual-de-un-alias-de-ruta-con-un-directrouteprovider-personalizado) contiene fragmentos de código en C# y parece ser que no se están mostrando con el correspondiente resaltado de sintaxis:

[image]

Así es como se ve en cambio [la misma pregunta en el sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26805356/manually-creating-route-alias-with-custom-directrouteprovider-causes-multiple-a) (el markdown es el mismo en ambos casos):

[image]

Comment: tampoco funciona para C++, me imagino que tampoco para el resto

Comment: buena atrapada!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed the site code highlighting settings so they apply by default on posts.

I have also set a few of the tags to use the related specific code highlighers (done for c++, angularjs, jasmine and karma-jasmine - these are all the language specific tags at the moment that have a specific highlighter).

Please add a translation of this answer to Spanish (and delete this line...)

Comment: I'll add the answer anyway, so that Juan can just copy& paste and then delete it (I guess he has enough workload already).

Comment: @Oded: I'm not sure if this is neccesary, but if it is, can you please add the pascal higlighter to the _delphi_ tag?

Answer (score 3):

Traducción de la respuesta de Oded:

He cambiado la configuración del resaltado de sintaxis para que se aplique de forma predeterminada en las publicaciones.

También he configurado algunas de las etiquetas para que usen sus resaltadores específicos (para c++, angularjs, jasmine y karma-jasmine - estas son las etiquetas de lenguaje que tienen un resaltador específico actualmente).