# Cómo cambiar el resaltado predeterminado de una etiqueta

Tags: soporte, resaltado-de-sintaxis, wiki-de-etiqueta

Sabiendo que [activó el resaltado de sintaxis para cada lenguaje](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2/127), y que falta configurarlo como predeterminado en muchas etiquetas, me pregunto ¿cuál sería la forma de solicitar que se cambie para una etiqueta específica?

Leí [en un comentario de BoltClock en metaSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270096/highlighting-language-of-xpath-tag-suggest-change-to-lang-xml#comment86464_270096) que sólo los mods pueden cambiar la configuración de lenguaje.

¿Deberíamos generar un post nuevo acá en meta solicitando cada cambio?