# Un poco más de color para SOes (en el código)

Tags: característica-nueva, etiquetas, resaltado-de-sintaxis

Gran parte de los fragmentos de código en las preguntas **no aparecen bien coloreados**.

El 30/10/15 se [habilitó el resaltado de sintaxis](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4/127) para el código de las publicaciones de SOes.
El funcionamiento está explicado en [¿Qué es el resaltado de sintaxis? ¿Cómo funciona?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1463/127)

Como verán, cada etiqueta define la sintaxis que se usará por omisión para resaltar el código de la publicación. Y si bien siempre se puede [especificar manualmente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) el lenguaje con un comentario html, hay muchas etiquetas a las que no les especificamos el lenguaje. Esto, [según BoltClock](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270096/highlighting-language-of-xpath-tag-suggest-change-to-lang-xml#comment86464_270096),sólo lo puede configurar un moderador. De más está decir la importancia de que el código, que es lo más importante en el sitio, se visualice correctamente.

¡A ponerle más color al sitio!

Comment: ¿Se le puede poner íconos a las [etiquetas como Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) en StackOverflow en inglés?

Comment: @ArtEze eso es cuando hay un auspiciante que paga por tener el logo en la etiqueta.

Comment: Nótese que la lista dada en [¿Qué es el resaltado de sintaxis? ¿Cómo funciona?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1464/83) es una copia de la original en inglés. Por tanto, creo que directamente quitaré ese listado de esa traducción y enlazaré con esta pregunta, pues contiene datos contrastados.

Comment: @fedorqui Yo creo que sigue siendo útil ese listado, ya que permite ver todos los lenguajes posibles para usar al especificar manualmente como `<!-- language: lang-python -->` por ejemplo

Comment: De acuerdo. En todo caso, siéntete libre de modificar esa lista o hacer lo que sea necesario para que sea útil.

Comment: Perdón, pero ando lento. Si quiero que las preguntas, digamos de [tag:django] estén correctamente coloreadas, ¿tendría que editar la etiqueta de la wiki o editar cada pregunta para asignarle a cada fragmento el lenguaje que corresponda? En este ejemplo, Django usa código de Python para el backend y HTML para el frontend, por lo que no hay forma de que una etiqueta funcione para ambos casos.

Comment: @toledano Esto no es algo que tengas que modificar. Es tarea para un moderador. En cuanto a [tag:django], considerando justamente eso es que lo puse (en la respuesta) como `default`, para que el script intente adivinar la sintaxis. Una vez implementado, si aún así no está coloreando como quisieras, entonces sí, una opción es agregar la etiqueta manualmente antes del fragmento de código. Por ejemplo: `<!-- language: lang-py -->`.

Comment: @fedorqui [hecho](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1463/127)!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tomando la lista de lenguajes de [¿Qué es el resaltado de sintaxis? ¿Cómo funciona?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1463/127), listo las etiquetas que están y las que faltan:

## Etiquetas que ya tienen asignado un lenguaje

- Lenguaje: `default`

  - [ajax](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax)
  - [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)
  - [asp](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp)
  - [asp.net](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net)
  - [asp.net-mvc](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc)
  - [awk](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk)
  - [bootstrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap)
  - [codeigniter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codeigniter)
  - [css](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) (tomado de SO, probablemente sea problemático poner como `lang-css`)
  - [css3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3)
  - [django](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) (tomado de SO, probablemente sea problemático poner como `lang-py`)
  - [entity-framework](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework)
  - [extjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extjs)
  - [google-apps-script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) (diferente a SO, pensando en archivos .html)
  - [grails](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grails)
  - [groovy](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groovy)
  - [hibernate](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hibernate)
  - [html](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) (tomado de SO, probablemente sea problemático poner como `lang-html`)
  - [html5](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5)
  - [ios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios)
  - [jasper-reports](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasper-reports)
  - [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) (tomado de SO, probablemente sea problemático poner como `lang-js`)
  - [jboss](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jboss)
  - [jquery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) (tomado de SO, probablemente sea problemático poner como `lang-js`)
  - [jsf](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf)
  - [json](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) (tomado de SO, probablemente sea problemático poner como `lang-json`)
  - [jpa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jpa)
  - [jsp](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsp)
  - [linq](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linq)
  - [linq-to-sql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linq-to-sql)
  - [matplotlib](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matplotlib)
  - [mono](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mono)
  - [.net](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net)
  - [netbeans](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netbeans)
  - [nhibernate](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nhibernate)
  - [polymer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polymer)
  - [razor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/razor)
  - [regex](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) (existe `lang-regex` pero no se ve bien, y la pregunta puede tener código en un lenguaje específico)
  - [servlets](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servlets)
  - [vue.js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js)
  - [wcf](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wcf)
  - [windows-forms](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-forms)
  - [wordpress](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress)
  - [wpf](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf)
  - [xcode](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode)
- Lenguaje: `lang-cs`

  - [c#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)
- Lenguaje: `lang-java`

  - [java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)
  - [swing](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing)
  - [glassfish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glassfish)
  - [java-8](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8)
  - [java-9](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-9)
  - [java-ee](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee)
  - [javafx](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javafx)
  - [spring](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring)
- Lenguaje: `lang-rb`

  - [ruby](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby)
- Lenguaje: `lang-xml`

  - [maven](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven)
- Lenguaje: `lang-vb`

  - [vb.net](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net)
  - [vb6](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6)
  - [vba](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba)
  - [vbscript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vbscript)
- Lenguaje: `lang-c`

  - [c](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)
  - [gcc](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc)
  - Otros relacionados: `lang-cc`, `lang-cpp`, `lang-cxx`, `lang-cyc`, `lang-m`
- Lenguaje: `lang-clj` (Clojure)

  - [clojure](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clojure)
- Lenguaje: `lang-coffee`

  - [coffeescript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coffeescript)
- Lenguaje: `lang-cpp`

  - [c++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)
  - [c++98](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98)
  - [c++11](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)
  - [c++1z](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1z)
  - [visual-c++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-c%2b%2b)
- Lenguaje: `lang-sql`

  - [mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql)
  - [postgresql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql)
  - [sql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql)
  - [sql-server](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server)
  - [oracle](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle)
  - [plsql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plsql)
  - [postgresql-9.3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql-9.3)
  - [sqlite](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite)
  - [sqlite3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite3)
  - [sql-server-2000](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2000)
  - [sql-server-2005](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2005)
  - [sql-server-2008](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008)
  - [sql-server-2008-r2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008-r2)
  - [sql-server-2012](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012)
  - [sql-server-2014](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2014)
  - [sql-server-2016](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2016)
  - [sql-server-ce](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-ce)
  - [tsql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql)
- Lenguaje: `lang-js` (JavaScript)

  - (javascript se configura como default)
  - [angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)
  - [d3.js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js)
  - [d3-v4.js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3-v4.js)
  - [ember.js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ember.js)
  - [ecmascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript)
  - [ecmascript-2015](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2015)
  - [extensión-google-chrome](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extensi%c3%b3n-google-chrome)
  - [firefox-webextensions](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-webextensions)
  - [gulp](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gulp)
  - [knockoutjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knockoutjs)
  - [nodejs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodejs)
  - [mongodb](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb)
  - [typescript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript)
  - Otros relacionados: `lang-javascript`
- Lenguaje: `lang-py` (Python)

  - [flask](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask)
  - [numpy](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy)
  - [pandas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas)
  - [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)
  - [python-2.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x)
  - [python-2.7](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7)
  - [python-3.x](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x)
  - [scipy](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scipy)
  - [web2py](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web2py)
  - Otros relacionados: `lang-python`, `lang-cv`
- Lenguaje: `lang-pascal`

  - [delphi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi)
  - [pascal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pascal)
  - [freepascal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/freepascal)
  - [delphi-2010](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi-2010)
- Lenguaje: `lang-php`

  - [phalcon](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phalcon)
  - [php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)
  - [php5](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php5)
  - [php7](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php7)
  - [symfony2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2)
  - [symfony3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3)
  - [yii](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii)
  - [yii2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii2)
- Lenguaje: `lang-swift`

  - [swift](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift)
  - [swift2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2)
  - [swift3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3)
- Lenguaje: `lang-perl` (Perl)

  - [perl](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl)
  - [perl6](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl6)
- Lenguaje: `lang-csh`

  - [csh](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csh)
- Lenguaje: `lang-go`

  - [go](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go)
- Lenguaje: `lang-hs` (Haskell)

  - [haskell](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell)
- Lenguaje: `lang-html`

  - (sin etiquetas, html se configura como default)
  - [xhtml](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xhtml)
- Lenguaje: `lang-latex`

  - [latex](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex)
  - Otros relacionados: `lang-tex`
- Lenguaje: `lang-lua`

  - [lua](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua)
- Lenguaje: `lang-matlab`

  - [matlab](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab)
- Lenguaje: `lang-ml`

  - [sfml](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sfml)
- Lenguaje: `lang-r`

  - [r](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)
- Lenguaje: `lang-rb` (Ruby)

  - [rails](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rails) (a diferencia de SO, que está como default)
  - Otros relacionados: `lang-ruby`
- Lenguaje: `lang-rust` (Rust)

  - [rust](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust)
  - Otros relacionados: `lang-rs`, `lang-rc`
- Lenguaje: `lang-scala`

  - [scala](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala)
- Lenguaje:  `lang-sh`

  - [bash](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash)
  - [shell](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell)
  - Otros relacionados: `lang-bash`, `lang-bsh`
- Lenguaje: `lang-xml`

  - [xaml](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xaml)
  - [xml](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml)
  - [xpath](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xpath)
  - [xsl](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xsl)

---

## Etiquetas para asignarles un lenguaje

- Lenguaje: `lang-none`

  - (sin etiquetas)
- Lenguaje: `lang-cl` (Lisp, Scheme)

  - (sin etiquetas, no encontré)
  - Otros relacionados: `lang-el`, `lang-lisp`, `lang-lsp`, `lang-scm`, `lang-ss`, `lang-rkt`
- Lenguaje: `lang-css`

  - (sin etiquetas, css se configura como default)
- Lenguaje: `lang-dart`

  - (sin etiquetas, no encontré)
- Lenguaje: `lang-erl` (Erlang)

  - (sin etiquetas, no encontré)
  - Otros relacionados: `lang-erlang`
- Lenguaje: `lang-fs` (OCaml, SML, F#, et al.)

  - (no se aplica a ninguna)
- Lenguaje: `lang-json`

  - (sin etiquetas, json se configura como default)
- Lenguaje:`lang-proto` (Protocol Buffers)

  - (sin etiquetas, no encontré)
- Lenguaje: `lang-regex`

  - (sin etiquetas, regex se configura como default)
- Lenguaje: `lang-s`

  - (sin etiquetas, no encontré)
- Lenguaje: `lang-vb`

  - [lotusscript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lotusscript) (**no existe actualmente**)
- Lenguaje: `lang-vhdl`

  - [vhdl](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vhdl)   (**no existe actualmente**)
  - Otros relacionados: `lang-vhd`
- Lenguaje: `lang-xsl` (**no existe ese resaltado**)

  - [xslt](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xslt)

---

## Etiquetas a las que NO se les asignará un lenguaje

Listo las más significativas para que quede claro cuáles no se están incluyendo y pueda haber opiniones diferentes sobre las mismas:

[android-layout](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-layout),
[android-sqlite](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sqlite),
[android-studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio),
[angularjs-2.0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0),
[apache](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache),
[array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array),
[asp.net-mvc-5](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-5),
[base-de-datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/base-de-datos),
[batch](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch),
[caml](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caml),
[cmd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmd),
[codeblocks](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codeblocks),
[consola](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/consola),
[cordova](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cordova),
[csv](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csv),
[eclipse](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse),
[excel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel),
[express](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/express),
[firebase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase),
[fortran](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran),
[git](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git),
[github](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github),
[gmail](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail),
[google](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google),
[google-hoja-de-calculo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hoja-de-calculo),
[google-maps](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps),
[gson](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gson),
[heroku](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heroku),
[.htaccess](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess),
[intellij](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij),
[ionic](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic),
[iphython](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphython),
[kivy](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kivy),
[laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel),
[laravel-4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-4),
[laravel-5](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-5),
[lenguaje-agnóstico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lenguaje-agn%c3%b3stico),
[linux](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux),
[mariadb](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mariadb),
[mvc](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc),
[mysqli](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysqli),
[nosql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nosql),
[oracle-11g](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11g),
[pcre](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pcre),
[phonegap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phonegap),
[phpmyadmin](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin),
[prolog](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog),
[qphython](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qphython),
[reactjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs),
[sailsjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sailsjs),
[spring-mvc](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-mvc),
[twig](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twig),
[uml](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uml),
[unity3d](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d),
[visual-studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio),
[visual-studio-2015](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2015).

Comment: El resaltado de sintaxis de C++ tiene errores y no está al día de los cambios ya aprobados para C++17, ¿Qué debo hacer para proponer correcciones?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster se gestiona desde el proyecto de [Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify). Más información en [¿Qué es el resaltado de sintaxis? ¿Cómo funciona?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1463/127).

Comment: @sstan puede ser, no estoy seguro. El tema es que, si tratan de consultas, ¿no deberían estar etiquetadas como [tag:SQL] al mismo tiempo? (ya lo hablamos en meta y creo que ambos estábamos con la minoría)... Lo que quiero evitar es que una pregunta etiquetada como [tag:java] [tag:mariadb] tome la sintaxis de SQL, cuando lo más probable es que tenga código Java... Al contrario, si busco coherencia, dejaría a [tag:MySQL] sin sintaxis, pero ambos sabemos que es un caso particular por el público que la frecuenta.

Comment: @Mariano toda la razón del mundo, como le dije a lois6b yo ya estaba cansadito de editar todas las de vb.net para añadírselo a mano. No sabía que era trabajo para los moderadores. Gracias por el toque de atención :)

Comment: Pues ... creo que mi labor está hecha, qué opinas?

Comment: @lois6b que sos un capo! Estoy festejando desde acá. Gracias totales!!!!

Comment: Muchas gracias Mariano por la iniciativa y @lois6b por hacerle seguimiento!