# ¿MSOes acepta respuestas en inglés del staff de Stack Overflow?

Tags: discusión, meta, stackexchange, idiomas

Supongamos un caso hipotético: hay un reporte de bug o alguna pregunta acá en Meta en la que sería relevante la respuesta de un empleado de Stack Overflow. La pregunta está en español (claro), y supongamos que al staff le interesa responder, pero se encuentra con la barrera del idioma.

¿Aceptamos una respuesta en inglés u otro idioma? ¿Cuál es la postura de MSOes?

Escucho opiniones...

> Probablemente haya diferentes posturas sobre si alguien la traduce, cómo, etc. Pero me gustaría centrar las opiniones sobre el primer paso: ¿puede publicar en inglés? ... después veremos el resto.

Comment: Cuando se referencia publicaciones o textos en inglés siempre se añade la traducción. Supongo que si él es incapaz de traducirla por su cuenta la pueda responder en inglés (y alguno de nosotros traducirla como dices) o puede que contacte con alguien que se la traduzca previamente para publicarla directamente asi (aunque si hubiera comentarios no los entendería). Yo personalmente **no veo mal que la publiacion se haga en inglés**, ya que para algo necesitamos de su opinion/punto de vista.

Comment: Interesante, y la verdad no había pensado en los comentarios, aunque me parece que entender y poder redactar están a niveles diferentes, pudiendo usar un traductor online, que puede hacer desastres en la traducción, pero el sentido general se entiende fácilmente... Creo que probablemente se entienda un comentario

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Por supuesto.

Lo principal es la respuesta, lo secundario el idioma. Dado que aquí bastante gente entiende el inglés, lo razonable creo que sería que lo publicara en inglés y que luego alguien se lo tradujera, incluyendo la traducción *junto con* la respuesta original (y no *en sustitución de*).

De hecho esto no solo aplica a los empleados, sino a toda aquella gente que participa en sitios específicos de un idioma. En Meta Spanish.SE alguna vez hemos solicitado opinión a algún experto de otro stack y [ha obrado así](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/2528/1).

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Lo suyo es que publiquen su respuesta, y luego alguien la edite y añada (no sustituya) la traducción

Comment: @Pikoh buen matiz. ¡Lo añado (sin sustituir lo ya dicho :P)!

Answer (score 0):

¿Como ha conseguido este empleado que no sabe español entender esa pregunta que sí está en español? ¿Quizás se la ha traducido alguien? ¿Por qué no traduce ese alguien también la respuesta?

¿No hay un gestor de comunidad que entiende los dos idiomas? ¿No está coordinado con el resto de empleados?

Aprecio que este hipotético empleado se tome el tiempo de responder. A este caso aplica lo que a todos: no escribas una respuesta incompleta, una que sabes que se va a tener que editar. Le sugiero que se pase por el chat de [SO en español](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com) y exponga su caso, en inglés pues no sabe español. Seguro que alguien se ofrece a traducirle la respuesta. Y después que publique la respuesta tanto con el texto original en inglés como con el traducido al español.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo en: ¿Cómo entendió la pregunta? Con un traductor online.. ¿Por qué no lo usó para responder? Se sabe que pueden ser bastante desastrosas, sirven para entender, pero no para publicar algo "serio".. ¿No hay un CM? Sí, el mismo que publica [en otro idioma](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6359/53463) en otras comunidades... Creo que permitir publicar sin intermediarios, ni perdiendo tiempo, facilita la interacción con el resto de la red... Sin embargo, aprecio que respondieras dando tu opinón (es exactamente lo que buscaba con la pregunta). Mi -1 va por punto de vista nomás

Comment: @Mariano Traducir al español para una comunidad hispanoparlante no es una pérdida de tiempo. Hay comentarios de desaprobación en tu enlace. Si no tuviese medios para traducir al portugués sería otra cosa, pero no hacerlo cuando los tiene es una falta de respeto hacia esa comunidad.

Comment: Creo que es diferente el caso de un gerente y el de un desarrollador.
 La tarea del desarrollador es hacer que esto funcione técnicamente,
 de ahí que usualmente se produzca esta situación, [como ya pasó en el pasado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4/83). En cuanto al CM,
 [estuvimos debatiendo](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/72224/2018/2/16) sobre este tema el otro día: tener un paso intermedio que es impredecible hace que aumenten las ganas de evitar ese paso y contactar directamente al desarrollador.